# Extract from text with python and regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, extract

Let's say we have text within which some quotes are stored in the form:

user:quote

we can have multiple quotes within a text.

```
Agatha Drake: She records her videos from the future? What is she, a
  f**ing time lord? Is she Michael J. Fox?

Harvey Spencer: This is just like that one movie where that one guy
  changed one tiny, little thing in his childhood to stop the girl of
  his dreams from being a crackhead in the future!
```

How can i extract the quotes (She records her videos from ..., This is just like that one movie....) from the text in python?

I tried

```
re.findall('\S\:\s?(.*)', text)
```

But it's not doing the job.

https://regex101.com/r/vH63Go/1

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Is a user always at the start of a line? [`(?m)^[^:\n]+:\s?((?:.+\n?)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ysr2n7/1) would be my approach then.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Proske. this is what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is following the consistent format of user at the start of a line and double newlines ending a quote, you could use this:

```
(?m)^[^:\n]+:\s?((?:.+\n?)*)
```

It uses multiline mode and matches the start of a line, followed by characters that are neither `:` nor newline, folllowed by `:`. Then captures all following lines with content.

Here's a demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ysr2n7/1).